# C++ access private member from C style function pointer initialized with lambda

Tags: c++, visual-c++

Here is a simple window class (members omitted for brevity):

```
class window {
public:
    window();
    window(const std::string& title, const gt::size2d& size, bool visible = true, bool fullscreen = false);

    NO_COPY(window);

    window(window&& o);
    window& operator=(window&& o);

    using close_callback = std::function<void()>;

    // members omitted ...

private:
    struct impl;
    struct impl_deleter {
        void operator()(impl* impl);
    };
    std::unique_ptr<impl, impl_deleter> m_pimpl;

    close_callback m_close_callback = []() { DD("Close callback"); };

    // ...
};
```

My goal is to call m_close_callback from GLFW window system, and I could implement something like this:

```
void close_callback_indirection(GLFWwindow* win)
{
    gt::window* winptr = static_cast<gt::window*>(glfwGetWindowUserPointer(win));
    if (winptr != nullptr) {
        winptr->m_close_callback(); // DOES NOT COMPILE
    }
}

gt::window::window(const std::string & title, const gt::size2d & size, bool visible, bool fullscreen)
    : m_pimpl{ nullptr }, m_close_callback{ []() {} }, m_size_callback{ [](const gt::size2d&) { } }
{
    // omitted GLFW and GL initialization here ...
    GLFWwindow* win = glfwCreateWindow(size.x, size.y, title.c_str(), nullptr, nullptr);
    m_pimpl.reset(new gt::window::impl);
    m_pimpl->glfw_win = win;

    glfwSetWindowUserPointer(win, this);

    glfwSetWindowCloseCallback(win, close_callback_indirection);


    // omitted rest ...
}
```

This, as expected, does not compile with message "'gt::window::m_close_callback': cannot access private member declared in class 'gt::window'".

However if I implement it like this:

```
gt::window::window(const std::string & title, const gt::size2d & size, bool visible, bool fullscreen)
    : m_pimpl{ nullptr }, m_close_callback{ []() {} }, m_size_callback{ [](const gt::size2d&) { } }
{
    // omitted GLFW and GL initialization here ...
    GLFWwindow* win = glfwCreateWindow(size.x, size.y, title.c_str(), nullptr, nullptr);
    m_pimpl.reset(new gt::window::impl);
    m_pimpl->glfw_win = win;

    glfwSetWindowUserPointer(win, this);

    // using lambda instead of function pointer
    glfwSetWindowCloseCallback(win, [](GLFWwindow* win) {
        gt::window* winptr = static_cast<gt::window*>(glfwGetWindowUserPointer(win));
        if (winptr != nullptr) {
            // Accessing private member here
            winptr->m_close_callback(); // WHY THIS WORKS?
        }
    });


    // omitted rest ...
}
```

Now it compiles and it works, if I press window close button I can see the debug message.

My understanding is that lambda without capture list can and in this case will be cast to function pointer so I guess that compiler will generate function code somewhere and pass in a pointer to that, but why does it have access to private member of window object? Is the generated function private member of window (or a friend)?

Can I rely on this behavior or is this something that is considered to be undefined?

I am using MSVC++ compiler

```
Microsoft (R) C/C++ Optimizing Compiler Version 19.16.27026.1 for x86
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

All lambdas have access to whatever is accessible at the point of their *declaration*. If you create a lambda in a member function of a class, that lambda can access anything that the member function itself would have access to. Always.

When a captureless lambda is converted to a function pointer, the function referred to by that pointer is identical to the lambda itself. Including its accessibility.